# How do you get unqualified names of fields using getFields()?

Tags: java, field

I have an example class:

```
public class A {
    public int x;
}
```

If I were to do something like the following:

```
Class a = Class.forName("A");
for (Field f : a.getFields()) {
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

I would get this as output:

> public int A.x

But what I really want is this:

> public int x

I've looked through the `Class` and `Field` APIs but there doesn't seem to be a method for this. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
String str=Modifier.toString(f.getModifiers()) + " " + f.getType() + " " + f.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to get rid of the `java.lang.` or any other qualifier that might appear in front of the return types? Like with Strings?

Comment: Try replacing `f.getType()` with `f.getType().getSimpleName()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just parse it out then...

```
System.out.println(f.toString().replace(a.getName() + ".", ""));
```